# How to build a single ES6 module from several TypeScript files (for a frontend library)

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The code of my frontend library is split into several source files.

Example:

```
// a.ts
function a() {}

// b.ts
function b() {}

// main.ts
const myLib = {
    a: a,
    b: b
}
```

I need to build one ES6 module (ie. one JavaScript file) that exports only `myLib`, as the default export.

I see two options. The first one:

1. Run `tsc` to compile each file to JavaScript;
2. Concatenate all the generated JS files into a single file `my-lib.js`;
3. Append the code needed by ES6 (`export …`).

The second one:

1. Concatenate all the TypeScript files into a single file `my-lib.ts`;
2. Append the export: `export default myLib`;
3. Run `tsc` on the concatenated file.

Both options are ugly and loose the `map` file.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I add an answer because today the correct way for a frontend library is to use **[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org)**.*

First, write ES6 modules, `import` and `export` them:

```
// file-a.ts
export function a() {}

// file-b.ts
export function b() {}

// main.ts
export { a } from "./file-a"
export { b } from "./file-b"
```

Then, compile the code to JavaScript using `tsc` with the option `module` set to `"es6"`.

Then, let Rollup build a flat bundle from the JavaScript code. For the code above, Rollup generates this bundle:

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
export { a, b };
```

See also:

- The Rollup REPL: https://rollupjs.org/repl
- The article: *[Webpack and Rollup: the same but different](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-and-rollup-the-same-but-different-a41ad427058c)*

Notice: The [definitive solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433) to **build the definition file** (`.d.ts`) is not implemented yet (March, 2018). [I still concatenate files](https://medium.com/@paleo.said/how-to-bundle-an-npm-package-with-typescript-and-rollup-f80e0f196189) with a Node.js script to generate exported types in a single TypeScript definition file.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to create a barrel file that will re export the modules.

```
// foo/a.ts
export function a() {}

// foo/b.ts
export function b() {}

// foo/index.ts
export {a} from './a';
export {b} from './b';
```

Then in your consumer:

```
import {a, b} from './foo';

a();
b();
```

Comment: The barrel file will be created automatically using any tool like gulp-umd, etc or we need to create in manually?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: I validated this answer because I think it is the only possible answer with the current standard and tools. But I still use my ugly procedure (the second one of my question). If someone finds a better solution, I am still interested.