# A single module from multiple js files using the typescript compiler

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

Let us suppose I have the following code file:

```
/// DoThinger.ts ///
class Model {
    ...
}
class Viewer {
    ...
}
class Controller {
    ...
}
export class DoThinger {
    model: Model;
    viewer: Viewer;
    controller: Controller;

    constructor() {
        this.model = new Model();
        this.viewer = new Viewer();
        this.controller = new Controller();
    }
    ...
}
```

(note: AMD module loading is only for illustration, it could be replaced with any kind of module loading for the scope of this question)
When running it through the typescript compiler with `"module": "amd", "outFile": "DoThinger.js"`, it yields, predictably, the following:

```
/// DoThinger.js ///
define("DoThinger", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Model = ...
    var Viewer = ...
    var Controller = ...
    var DoThinger = ...
    exports.DoThinger = DoThinger;
});
```

Let us further suppose that the code in each of the MVC gets large enough that it's unwieldy to keep it in one giant source file. So each MVC gets its own source file: model.ts, viewer.ts, controller.ts.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the aforementioned compiler result without jumping through some hoops. I have tried the following:

**(0) Separate the files and use ///<reference path=""/>**

The source files is broken down and `DoThinger.ts` is prepended reference paths to the now-missing definitions. Unsurprisingly, the output is not what I wanted:

```
/// DoThinger.js ///
var Model = ...
var Viewer = ...
var Controller = ...
define("DoThinger", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var DoThinger = ...
    exports.DoThinger = DoThinger;
});
```

The definitions are left dangling and within the global namespace (correct me if I'm wrong).

**(1) Use export / import**

Each of our MVC's source file is prepended an `export` statement:

```
/// model.js ///
export class Model {
    ...
}
```

While our DoThinger's source file is prepended with matching `imports`:

```
/// DoThinger.ts ///
import { Model } from "./model"
import { Viewer } from "./viewer"
import { Controller } from "./controller"

export class DoThinger {
    ...
}
```

which yields multiple modules concatenated in the same file:

```
/// DoThinger.js ///
define("model", ...
define("viewer", ...
define("controller", ...
define("DoThinger", ...
```

This is better than (0), but far from what I want. While the model could be decoupled a bit and indeed published as its own module, both the viewer and the controller have varying degrees of coupling among themselves and with our DoThinger, as they are DoThinger specific.

I will always wish to load the viewer, the controller and the model (if it doesn't have a drop-in replacement) along with DoThinger.

**(2) Use a Makefile**

I ditched `"outFile"` entirely and changed `"module"` to `"none"`. I then wrote a Makefile that:

1. instructs tsc to compile the .ts files to .js
2. concatenates the .js files
3. adds the desired module definitions at the top and the bottom of concatenated file.

This obtains the desired output, but it feels hackish, considering the compiler already has flips and switches that deal with various kinds of modules.

---

I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597404/how-to-build-a-single-es6-module-from-several-typescript-files

Comment: Could I ask why the `(1) use export / import` result offends you?

Comment: @Paarth, offended might be too strong of a word. I just want a plain DoThinger.js that could be inserted in a boring old single <script> tag in a boring old thin client, server-rendered website without any setting up of module loaders. The AMD module syntax is just for illustration, let's say I use UML and I want to deliver my library as a global var if all else fails.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you considered using TS namespaces for the `///<reference path` solution?

Comment: @Paarth If I wrap each file in the same namespace, I still have to export the MVC classes to be used in the main file (afaik, `export` specifies extra-namespace use).

Granted, they all compile nicely as descendants of the same `var myNameSpace` but as soon as I export one of the namespaces, the reference paths break and the problem at (0) is duplicated.

If I export all 4 instances of the namespace, I mirror the situation from (1).  Even if I use `///<amd-module name` to specify the same module name in each file, I just have 4 modules defined with the same name, which I doubt is valid.