# Build and distribute a Typescript project

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a typescript project, that when I develop it, the code is spread among many files.

I want to distribute that project a a single js and d.ts file - what's the best way to do that?

Comment: It depends where you want to distribute your project. If you want it to be available to all over the world then you can use npm. If this project is business related then you probably should not publish it outside of your organization. With internal use a lot depends on your project tooling.

Comment: I'll use npm. But my question is more focused on merging the multiple files and creating one js and one d.ts file with  a simple step

Comment: BTW if the question was not about how to distribute but how to create a single js bundle then you have several options: if you use reference style of imports and namespaces then typescript can produce bundle by itself; if you use es6 imports then there are external bundlers for example webpack.

Comment: and for generating declaration files look at `--declaration` flag of [typescript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: @PavelAgarkov When you say "typescript can produce bundle by itself" , can you tell me how or direct me to an article on that?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37597404/3786294 .

Comment: that's just a command line tool: tsc -p path_to_your_tsconfig_json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you package your file, there is normally no need to combine it into a single file. Using a package manager (such as NPM) your files will be bundled into a package that you can keep private, or make public, and that package has all the files needed to run your module.

With TypeScript in particular, you would package the `.js` and `.d.ts` files, which means your package will work for both TypeScript and JavaScript consumers. You wouldn't add the `.ts` files to the package.

If you are targeting both browser and Node environments, you can use `UMD` modules, which work in both environments.

Practical example - TypeSpec.

Please note - I have put entire files below to ensure the context is there, but the important bits are usually one or two lines, which I have highlighted.

TypeScript config file - the important bits are the "module" kind, and emitting "declaration" files.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "umd", // <--
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "declaration": true, // <--
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  }
}
```

Gulp file - this moves the files into a `dist` folder, incuding the package.json and readme files, but most importantly all of the JavaScript and type definitions.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('./node_modules/requirejs/require.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./lib'));

    // This bit moves type definitions
    gulp.src('./Scripts/TypeSpec/*.d.ts')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));

    // And this bit moves the JavaScript
    gulp.src('./Scripts/TypeSpec/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));

    gulp.src('../README.md')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

    gulp.src('./package.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

The package.json file hints where the main source file and type information can be found in the "main" and "types" sections:

```
{
  "author": "Steve Fenton",
  "name": "typespec-bdd",
  "description": "BDD framework for TypeScript.",
  "keywords": [
    "typespec",
    "typescript",
    "bdd",
    "behaviour",
    "driven"
  ],
  "version": "0.7.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeSpec",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeSpec/issues",
  "license": "(Apache-2.0)",
  "files": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeSpec"
  },
  "main": "./src/TypeSpec.js", <-- main file
  "types": "./src/TypeSpec.d.ts", <-- type information starts here
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "*"
  }
}
```

You now have a "dist" folder with just the files you need to package. You can try it out without publishing to NPM using.

```
npm pack
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - There is still one thing I'm not clear on - I want it all to be in a single import statement in typescript, so my code users will just do <code> import * as utils from '@module.utils'  </code>
While when I develop, I'll have it in separate easier to maintain files.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Part of that is architectural, if you look at the TypeSpec project, it re-exports anything that the consumers might need, which means they only need to know about the top-level module file, i.e. if someone imports the top level module, they have access to the public interface of the module... and they don't need to know that there may be many files supporting that interface.

Comment: Thanks -  I appreciate the help