# How can I split up a type definition file?

Tags: typescript, typedef, expo

I've started writing a Type Definition file for [Expo](https://expo.io/), and the file is getting pretty long, so I am looking for a way to split it across multiple files.

The file contains multiple namespaces, so there is a natural way to split it. Splitting it across multiple `d.ts` files would also out of the box in the demo project. But right now you have to update the `expo.d.ts` file manually, if you're using it in another project, so it's convenient, that there is only a single file. Also, if I ever was to convince the maintainers of Expo to include this file, I am also quite sure, that it would need to a be a single file, since the `types` property in `package.json` can only point to one file.

Any suggestions?

Link to the type definition file:
https://github.com/janaagaard75/expo-and-typescript/blob/master/src/expo.d.ts

Comment: In your "one true file" export the types you want from all of the individual files. See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684736/215552).